# Where does The wolverine end credit scene fall?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, chronology, x-men-days-of-future-past, the-wolverine

In [X-Men: Days of Future Past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3a_Days_of_Future_Past), where does the end credit scene of [The Wolverine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolverine_%28film%29) fall? I mean when did that event occur in Days of Future Past?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56921/23386.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this Marvel timeline](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline):

In **1973**:

> "Early" scenes of X-Men: Days of Future Past are set.
>   Mark I Sentinels are
>   created. Between 1973 and 1996, Trask produces 8,732 Mark I Sentinels
>   for the governments of the United States, China, Russia, Israel, Saudi
>   Arabia, France, India and the United Kingdom.

In **2013**:

> The year that "The Wolverine" is set in.
>   Mark X Sentinels announced.

In **2015**:

> Professor X and Magneto meet Wolverine at an airport.

In **2023**:

> "Future" scene of X-Men: Days of Future Past are set.

So effectively, X-Men: Days of Future Past contains scenes from **1973** and **2023**. The Wolverine end credit scene takes place in **2015**.

Comment: That Wikia is unsourced, where did these dates originate?

Comment: I'm assuming they've originated from a superfan who has kept a tab on the dates.  I can update this answer when I get home and search for a second source of confirmation on the dates

Comment: @Keen: After doing a bit more digging, it's just someone who has kept track of the dates. Wolverine is set in 2013 and the airport scene is labelled "two years later", i.e. 2015. X-Men Days of Future Past is set in both 1973 and 2023 according to numerous sources online.

Comment: Now I wonder 2 more things, when was weapon x in this timeline and when was the "new" new future in DOFP...

Comment: Are they mentioned on the timeline in the linked page?

Comment: Weapon x is in there, however now we are left to believe that that timeline has changed so I guess its no longer correct dates. Also the end future of DOFP is not mentioned so I'm guessing 2023 is both the year of the old future and the new future in DOFP? Dammit why can't they just fit it nicely :o)

Comment: @Jared *"so I'm guessing 2023 is both the year of the old future and the new future in DOFP"* - Of course it is, since *Kitty* said that *Logan* would awake at exactly that time, but with the changed future as the new one. So he certainly "awakes" at the same *time* of the events in the future part of the movie, just in his new changed history self, which is safely sleeping in *Xavier*-manor. But I can udnerstand your confusion, seeing that people like *Rogue*, *Jean* or *Bobby* don't seem to have aged much since *Last Stand*'s ~2010.